# Get the min seconds and show on page

Tags: javascript, html, store

I want to store the seconds and show the minimum seconds after each click on the page. How can I do it? Thanks in advance for your assists.

```js
document.getElementById("shape").onclick=function(){
    document.getElementById("shape").style.display="none";
    
    var end=new Date().getTime();
    var netTime= ((end-start)/1000);

    document.getElementById("zamanim").innerHTML=netTime + " sn.";
        
    appearAfterDelay();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with an array "const". Then get the min value by Math.min() –

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).